# C# как запустить браузер, передавая ему user_agent и прокси

Tags: c#, windows, браузер

Подскажите, как можно программно запустить браузер(знаю, что есть класс Process, но как я понял там нельзя передавать кастомный user-agent). Может кто знает метод как открыть браузер(Chrome, Firefox, Opera,IE explorer, никаких специфических) и передать ему свои данные?

Comment: Наверное как-то можно, но про какой именно браузер речь? Для каждого оно выполняется по-своему, если вообще возможно. Через командную строку этого точно не сделать. Вопрос слишком общий. И `user-agent` пишется через дефис.

Comment: Зависит от конкретного браузера и его возможностей. Стандартов как таковых нету. Читайте спецификацию каждого из браузеров и смотрите что они могут, а что нет. Допустим сменить агента у хрома просто `chrome.exe --user-agent="My User Agent"`, прокси также `--proxy-server="прокся"`.

Comment: @aepot `5 гигантов` Firefox, Chrome, Opera, IE. Ошибся, 4-х достаточно

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо, это вы имеете ввиду запрос через класс Process?

Comment: Не вижу смысла подменять user-agent. Многие сайты адаптируются под тип браузера, чтобы использовать его особенности и отображать контент правильно. Если изменить агента, часть сайтов может начать работать криво. То есть кроме негативного эффекта, я в этом не вижу ничего полезного. Хотите поменять агента - поменяйте браузер. Как вы сказали, целых 5 вариантов есть.

Comment: И забудьте про IE уже, он несовместим с интернетом и давно умер. Используйте Edge вместо него.

Comment: @artemgh Да, это аргументы запуска. Вообще, не в обиду, просто совет... Я вам 
 советую для начала познать основы языка, написать простые проекты по типу калькулятора, мб игры своей (змейки), потом попробовать поработать с парсингом сайтов, понять что такое HTTP, как это все работает. Ну и такими мелкими шажками идите к цели (если конечно не передумаете). Просто на данный момент, по вам видно, что вы совершенно не понимаете что делаете. Вы как ребенок, который наивно предполагает, что сможет построить ракету. Даже сама ваша идея "антидетект браузера" (или как там), по сути, изначально мертва.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да, конечно, я с Вами соглашусь, но что поделать, тем более по законам РФ, я и так ребёнок...

Comment: Давайте прямо: вы хотите накручивать голоса/просмотры, для чего и пытаетесь сделать антидетект браузер. Кхм... Про IP слышали?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov насчёт накрутки нет

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо, большое, работает, но конечно Chrome не настолько глуп, допустим android он задать не даёт, но Linux, Mac os, прекрасно работает

Comment: @artemgh Ну, я вам изначально говорил, что ваша затея с "антидетект браузером" ерунда, особенно, если вы это реализуете как обертку над уже готовым браузером, а они каждый чих отслеживают) Чтоб понять вы это или нет, ресурс может многое сделать, от банальной проверки агента, до полноценной проверки фингерпринта браузера. Так что, если хотите "антидетект браузер", то пишите свой, с нуля (ну или хотяб возьмите ядро хромиум и модифицируйте его), который будет иметь необходимые механизмы. И тут уже встает вопрос о необходимости этого, ведь таких браузеров сотни)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да, конечно, но в учебных целях, всё отлично. Но всё же поищу насколько большие возможности у такой "обертки" смогу ли я передать например куки...